# javascript a href title change (dunno how to describe it otherwise)

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

Because english isn't my first language, I don't know how else to draft my question, so sorry in advance if a problem like this has already been resolved on this website.
Anyways, I have this JavaScript link, something like that:

```
<a href="javascript:patonglet1m()">something</a>
```

But that's not really a problem. What I want to do is to change this text (this one is from Google Chrome), when you hover on the link: [here's what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4AvR.png).
Is it even possible? Can it say something I want it to say?
Sorry, perhaps it is a stupid question, but I'm new to all this.

Comment: Well it's not a stupid question but a curious one, when you hover on links on websites than browser shows the `href` value(link web address) at the bottom left corner. It is a part of browser functionality or function. You have already provided text for the link so no worries about at that corner.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rana Oh okay, thank you! I shall not worry about it then.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add abbrevation in html,
you have to add hrml tag `<abbr title="hey im hover abbrevation"><a href="javascript:">something</a></abbr>`